# locating a richtextbox in a datagrid row

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, richtextbox

In my DataGrid, each row contains a RichTextBox.

**EDIT** : Here is how the RTB is placed in the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="columnText" x:Uid="columnText" 
                                    Header="Text" 
                                    Width="*" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    SortMemberPath="Text"
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource mainFormGridCell_columnText}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The DataTemplate is defined in a ResourceDictionary and looks roughly like this :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="mainFormGridCell_columnText">
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbDiff" x:Uid="rtbDiff"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I need to do at runtime is fill the richtextbox of the SelectedItem with a FlowDocument. I now use the extension methods described [here](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html) to find the Cell that contains that Control. With that I do the following :

```
DataGridCell cell = this.dgTexts.GetCell( this.dgFreetexts.GetSelectedRow(), 0 );
object ob = cell.Template.FindName( "rtbDiff", cell );
```

No matter how, I never find any Child with that Name - FindName always returns NULL.
Does anybody have any ideas how I can improve my search for the RichTextBox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls).